# HTML5 video tag is not supporting .mp4 video file with codec MPEG4

Tags: video, html5-video, video-codecs

I have .mp4 files with codec MPEG4 but I am facing problem when i try to display those videos in web page.

**Note:** I can able to play same videos in windows media player and Movies player.

I don't know how to resolve this issue.

My Questions are:

1) why HTML5 video tag is not supporting when video is fine with Windows Media player and Movies player ?

2) How to display these .mp4 files with codec MPEG4 in web page.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. It will only support h.264 or probablly VP9. The reason for standards should be obvious. Supporting may codecs is a lot of extra work, and a lot of extra costs to pay the roalities patents for the codecs.

2) how to display -> transcode to h.264.

Comment: i tried by converting MPEG4 to h.264 video , quality is so much reduced and it is showing first frame for almost of 20 seconds and then it started showing remaining frames why it is happening. do you know any .net libraries to convert .mpeg4 to h.264?

Comment: Every question should have it’s own stackoverflow post.